# Get counting numbers merged from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table called 'services' with this structure: institution, Role

```
    Institution     |   Role
    Human Ressource |   Responsable
    Human Ressource |   Responsable
    Human Ressource |   Agent
    Human Ressource |   Agent
    Human Ressource |   Chief
    IT Service      |   Responsable
    IT Service      |   Agent
    Client Relate   |   Responsable 
    Client Relate   |   Chief
    Control Mgm     |   Responsable
    Control Mgm     |   Agent
    Control Mgm     |   Agent
```

and a query to get counting numbers of Roles per Institutions like:

```
    SELECT a.institution, Responsable, Agent, Chief
    FROM
    (
      SELECT a.institution
      FROM services a
      WHERE a.month = '2019-04'
      GROUP BY a.institution
    ) a,
    (
      SELECT b.institution, NULLIF(count(b.role) ,0) AS Responsable
      FROM services b
      WHERE
        b.month = '2019-04' AND
        b.role = 'Responsable'
      GROUP BY b.institution
    ) b,
    (
      SELECT c.institution, NULLIF(count(c.role), 0) AS Agent
      FROM services c
      WHERE
        c.month = '2019-04' AND
        c.role = 'Agent'
      GROUP BY c.institution
    ) c,
    (
      SELECT d.institution, NULLIF(count(d.role), 0) AS Chief
      FROM services d
      WHERE
        d.month = '2019-04' AND
        d.role = 'Chief'
      GROUP BY d.institution
    ) d
    WHERE
      a.institution = b.institution AND
      a.institution = d.institution
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY a.institution ASC
```

What I want to achive in one sql statement is a result like:

```
    Institution     |   Responsable |   Agent   |   Chief   
    Human Ressource |   2           |   2       |   1
    IT Service      |   1           |   1       |   0
    Client Relate   |   1           |   0       |   1
    Control Mgm     |   1           |   2       |   0
```

But i obtain a very strange resultset

```
    institution     |   Responsable |   Agent   |   Chief
    Client Relate   |   1           |   2       |   1
    Human Ressource |   2           |   2       |   1
```

I've created here a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7163f5/1)

Any idea will be highly appreciated. Tnx

Comment: There's no month column here. What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for giving out Table Schema, sample data and desired output.
Try this one.

```
SELECT institution,
       Sum(CASE WHEN role = 'Responsable' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS Responsable,
       Sum(CASE WHEN role = 'Agent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS Agent,
       Sum(CASE WHEN role = 'Chief' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS Chief
FROM   services
GROUP  BY institution
```

You can also add where clause if you want.
Example: `WHERE  month = '2019-04'`

Output

```
+------------------+--------------+--------+-------+
|   institution    | Responsable  | Agent  | Chief |
+------------------+--------------+--------+-------+
| Client Relate    |           1  |     0  |     1 |
| Control Mgm      |           1  |     2  |     0 |
| Human Ressource  |           2  |     2  |     1 |
| IT Service       |           1  |     1  |     0 |
+------------------+--------------+--------+-------+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7163f5/16/0

Answer (score 2):

use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT a.institution,
       coalesce(count(case when role = 'Responsable' then 1 end),0) AS Responsable,
       coalesce(count(case when role = 'Agent' then 1 end),0) AS Agent,
       coalesce(count(case when role = 'Chief' then 1 end),0) AS Chief
FROM services a
WHERE a.month = '2019-04'
GROUP By a.institution
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this using `CASE` statements and then aggregating the results:

```
SELECT  institution,
        SUM(Responsable) AS Responsable,
        SUM(Agent) AS Agent,
        SUM(Chief) AS Chief
  FROM  (
        SELECT  institution,
                CASE
                  WHEN role = 'Responsable' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END AS Responsable,
                CASE
                  WHEN role = 'Agent' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END AS Agent,
                CASE
                  WHEN role = 'Chief' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END AS Chief
          FROM services
          WHERE `month` = '2019-04'
        ) a
  GROUP BY institution
  ORDER BY institution ASC;
```

This will create a result set with a 1 in the appropriate column for each row, and then group them together by the `institution` and `SUM` the count for each of the rows with that institution.

Results:

```
Client Relate   1   0   1
Control Mgm     1   2   0
Human Ressource 2   2   1
IT Service      1   1   0
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7163f5/7) showing this.